# I uninstalled an app,but did not clear space

Tags: google-play-games

So i am using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 and i recently had this game called 'Bully:Scholarship Edition'(got tired a while of the GTAs) and i saw the app was having 5.30GB memory size
I tapped uninstall and the app,the obb(2.5GB) and the data are gone from my device,but i keep having only 500MB free
I do not have any cache to delete
I did restart my device a couple times
Nothing seems to work

Please help me if you can

Comment: Use an app like [DiskInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) and identify the partition which has only 500MB free (and edit your question and add a screnshot of the partitions). Your device has multiple partitions and the deleted app may not had used space on every of the partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning apps like Clean Master will find and get rid of residue files if there are any present on the device, you can then uninstall it when your done if you don't want all the advert notifications.